# Inside the while loop i am not able to print a string

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to the Scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
cat /proc/net/dev > net
while read -r line
do
    tx_bytes=$(echo $line | tac | head -n1 | awk '{print $2}')
    echo $tx_bytes  
done <net
```

I want to store the tx bytes into the  tx_byte variable. when i tried the above script its printing all the lines which are there in net file.

net file.

```
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
wlp9s0b1: 180051861  145907    0    0    0     0          0         0 13205537   85626    0    0    0     0       0          0
    lo: 4136388   45561    0    0    0     0          0         0  4136388   45561    0    0    0     0       0          0
enp5s0: 11824249235 9325207    0    1    0     0          0         0 364193641 4070320    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `tac | head -n1`? Your while loop will read line-by-line, so `$line` in each case is a single line of the file.

Comment: I am trying to print 11824249235

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print value from last line:

```
awk 'END{print $2}' /proc/net/dev
```

Print value from second column with `enp5s0:` in first column.

```
awk '$1=="enp5s0:" {print $2}' /proc/net/dev
```